# Correct way to find out all the superclasses of a Class in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I'm a novice, and I seem to be getting multiple errors on this.
All I want is a for or while loop to print out all the superclasses of a certain Class.

Here is the pseudocode of what I want:

```
IDontKnowWhatClass *superClassName;

while (superClassName != nil)
{
    superClassName = [[superClassName class] superclass];
    NSLog(print the name);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Class superClassName = [self class];

while (superClassName != nil)
{
        superClassName = [superClassName superclass];
        NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromClass(superClassName));
}
```

If you know a class itself like `NSString` then,

```
Class superClassName = [NSString class];
```

You can store the class name to a string like

```
NSString *className = NSStringFromClass(superClassName);
```

And if you want to create an object of the class from which class name is stored in a string like

```
id object = [[NSClassFromString(className) alloc] init];
```

Comment: This is very nice... It works out of the box. Wish I could give it two upvotes so I can separate it from all the other ones that I only gave 1 upvote. It is very close to what I posted in the question

Comment: It seems asking an initialized object its superclass is the way to go. Any way to do this at runtime an be able to cast a normal NSString as the actual name of a Class and do this at runtime, so I can type the name of the class I want in say a textfield and have the system ask the Class with that name the message superclass and go into that while loop. Could you please edit your answer to include a completed working example of the code so I can mark this off as the answer.

Comment: `superClassName` is not a name. You should rename the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Use NSObject method names as :

```
objc_property_t class_getProperty(Class cls, const char *name)

//Returns a property with a given name of a given class.
```

Keep on finding till you get the NSObject as it is supermost class

Use this method to check for equality :

```
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)object;
```

or

```
[object isKindOfClass:[SomeClass class]]
```

[Documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/class_getSuperclass)

This will work

Comment: This seems correct but is waaaay above my league. All you get is an up vote :)... I have a lot of ground to cover before I get to the Objective-C Runtime.

Comment: Tried all the answers and it seems yours is closer to the truth than I previously thought. The correct code should be able to cast a normal NSString as the actual name of a Class and do this at runtime, so I can type the name of the class I want in say a textfield and have the system ask the Class with that name the message superclass and go into that while loop. Could you please edit your answer to include a completed working example of the code so I can mark this off as the answer.

Comment: Tell me for what class you want that ?

Comment: For example NSMutableDictionary

Answer (score 1):

You can call `superclass` method on your current class until it gets equal to Nil (that will happen for root class, i.e. `NSObject`).

```
Class c = [IDontKnowWhatClass class];

while (c)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass(c));
    c = [c superclass];
}
```

Comment: Listen. I just ran your code and it never enters the while loop. When i Debug "c" seems to have a value, but it just skips over the while loop and never prints anything.

Comment: It seems the value of "c" is just "class" and not "classname" if all is execute is 
Class c = [self class];

while (c)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass(c));
    c = [c superclass];
} then all is well... it seems *superClassName needs to be initialized properly for the code to work.

Comment: I fixed it. It seems the first line creates the *superClassName object but it does not initialize it. The correct code should be able to cast a normal NSString as the actual name of a Class and do this at runtime. So I can type the name of the class I want in say a textfield and have the system ask the Class with that name the message superclass and go into that while loop.

Comment: @unmircea, sure superClassName object should be initialized for the code to work. I've fixed the code

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString* classString = @"IDontKnowWhatClass";
Class class = NSClassFromString(classString);
while (class != nil){
    NSLog(@"%@", [class description]);
    class = [class superclass];
}
```

Comment: This is correct. You get an upvote, but I can't choose it as my answer as it redirects to a scrollview and I don't know what that it. I will read about it.

Comment: It seems asking an initialized object its superclass is the way to go. Any way to do this at runtime an be able to cast a normal NSString as the actual name of a Class and do this at runtime, so I can type the name of the class I want in say a textfield and have the system ask the Class with that name the message superclass and go into that while loop. Could you please edit your answer to include a completed working example of the code so I can mark this off as the answer.

Comment: @unmircea, there's NSClassFromString function to get class object from string (if it exists)

Comment: Edited my code, which should now do what you asked. The string in the first line is the string of the class you want to query. Thanks to @Vladimir for the function.